# ObjectContext instead of DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm completely new to *EntityFramewok* but I have to write a project with my friend with deadline next week. He created Data Access Layer and shared code with me. After using ADO.NET Entity Data Model I found errors in his classes. It appeared that he used Add() method which I don't have. After quick search I found that his generated templated for Context inherits after `DbContext` and mine after `ObjectContext`.
Why does it happen so?
We are using the same version of *EntityFramework*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your comment - This is because you are using VS2010 and he is using VS2012. In VS2012 the default code generation changed from ObjectContext to DbContext. You could change it back to ObjectContext by deleting T4 templates and changing the "Code Generation Strategy" setting from "None" to "Default".

However there is more to the story - out-of-the box VS2010 supported only v2 EDMX while VS2012 supported V3 EDMX, if you create a model on VS2012 you won't be able to open it in VS2010. Similarly I am not sure if you can target .NET Framework 4.5 in VS2010 but it is the default in VS2012.

Ideally you should use the same environment because there is simply to many differences between what you can do in VS2010 and VS2012. If you cannot unify your environments I would recommend targeting the same .NET Framework (would have to probably be .NET Framework 4 unless VS2010 can target .NET Framework 4.5) using EF6 (latest and greatest, bin deployable, does not depend on System.Data.Entity.dll - important given the .NET Framework 4.5 is an in-place update and you never know whether your app targeting .NET Framework 4 is actually running on .NET Framework 4 or .NET Framework 4.5) and using CodeFirst approach to avoid v2 vs. v3 Edmx problems.

Comment: And is it possible to make VS2010 behave like 2012?

Comment: In what sense? In general if it was possible to make VS2010 behave like VS2012 people would not move to VS2012. In case of EF you can think of enums in the EF Designer - they are not supported in VS2010 and it will never be while they work in VS2012. Interestingly we were able to make the EF Designer that ships with VS2013 work with VS2012 (there is a standalone download that replaces the original VS 2012 version) but the technical gap between VS2010 and VS2012 was to big. If this is about costs you may try Express versions - they are free and you can get VS2013 experience for both of you.

Comment: This helped me. I've seen similar answers, but they fail to mention that you FIRST need to delete the existing T4 templates.

Answer (score 2):

`DbContext` simply acts like a wrapper around `ObjectContext`. What you could do is create a helper class with a method that exposes your `ObjectContext` from `DbContext`:

```
using System.Data.Objects;

public static class DbContextExtentions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Exposes the ObjectContext from DbContext
    /// </summary>
    public static ObjectContext ToObjectContext(this DbContext dbContext)
    {
        return (dbContext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var myObjectContext = DbContextExtentions.ToObjectContext(myFriendsDbContext);
```

Comment: Thank you for this idea. Maybe we'll use it. Or we can just use AddObject() instead of Add(). But I'm  still wondering why his generated code if different than mine. Can it be because he's using Visual Studio 2012 and I have 2010?

Comment: About the generated code - Are you both connecting to the same data source? Are your models in sync?

Comment: No, we are both using local MS SQL servers. And models are the same. I used his .sql to create them

Comment: Wait, if you defined an extension method (by using "this DbContext" as an argument), why call it with DbContextExtentions.ToObjectContext(myFriendsDbContext) instead of simply calling myFriendsDbContext.ToObjectContext()? That's exactly what extension methods make possible.